# Llamar una GUI desde Otra GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un vacío del conocimiento con lo referente al llamado de GUI, me explico:
***1°. Tengo un script de pyhton con tkinter llamado principal.py*** Aquí solo tengo 4 botones.

```py
import Tkinter as tk 
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
b0 = Button(root, text="Programa 1").pack()
b1 = Button(root, text="Programa 2").pack()
b2 = Button(root, text="Programa 3").pack()
b3 = Button(root, text="Programa 4").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

***2°. Tengo otro script llamado programa1.py*** Donde tengo configurado un programa con varios `def xxxx()` y otros elementos visuales , pero para ejemplificar tengo lo siguiente:

```py
import Tkinter as tk 
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
l0 = Label(root, text="Soy Etiqueta 1").pack()
l1 = Label(root, text="Soy Etiqueta 2").pack()
l2 = Label(root, text="Soy Etiqueta 3").pack()
l3 = Label(root, text="Soy Etiqueta 4").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

***La pregunta : ¿Como puedo llamar desde principal.py a programa#.py con los botones que tengo asignado?*** Se que se tiene que definir una función, lo intente con las hijas `TopLevel` pero se me abren otras ventanas vacías. Discupen si les quito su tiempo soy nuevo en esto.
Gracias Anticipadas!!
Algunas Características: interprete de python 2.7.12, SO: Windows 10. IDE: Pycharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumiendo, podemos tener dos situaciones:

- **Se trata de dos o más aplicaciones distintas**, tu aplicación "principal" se limita a ejecutar las otras aplicaciones, actuando como una especie de lanzador de aplicaciones simplemente:

  En este caso puedes ejecutar el script en un proceso independiente mediante el módulo `subprocess`, por ejemplo (simplificando mucho):

  **principal.py**

  ```
  import subprocess
  import Tkinter as tk 


  def abrir_programa1():
      subprocess.Popen(["python", "programa1.py"])

  def abrir_programa2():
      pass

  def abrir_programa3():
      pass

  def abrir_programa4():
      pass

  root = tk.Tk()
  tk.Button(root, text="Programa 1", command=abrir_programa1).pack()
  tk.Button(root, text="Programa 2", command=abrir_programa2).pack()
  tk.Button(root, text="Programa 3", command=abrir_programa3).pack()
  tk.Button(root, text="Programa 4", command=abrir_programa4).pack()
  root.mainloop()
  ```

  **programa1.py**

  ```
  import Tkinter as tk 

  root = tk.Tk()
  tk.Label(root, text="Soy Etiqueta 1").pack()
  tk.Label(root, text="Soy Etiqueta 2").pack()
  tk.Label(root, text="Soy Etiqueta 3").pack()
  tk.Label(root, text="Soy Etiqueta 4").pack()
  root.mainloop()
  ```
- **Se trata de ventanas hijas o secundarias, formando parte de la misma aplicación:**

  En este caso debes usar `Toplevel` para generarla. Generalmente [para evitar problemas inesperados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/283265/15089), debes tener un solo ciclo principal (mainloop) por proceso/aplicación. Simplemente implementa el contenido de tu ventana en tu script y luego impórtalo en el principal:

  **principal.py**

  ```
  import Tkinter as tk 
  import programa1


  def abrir_programa1():
      programa1.crear_toplevel(root)

  def abrir_programa2():
      pass

  def abrir_programa3():
      pass

  def abrir_programa4():
      pass

  root = tk.Tk()
  tk.Button(root, text="Programa 1", command=abrir_programa1).pack()
  tk.Button(root, text="Programa 2", command=abrir_programa2).pack()
  tk.Button(root, text="Programa 3", command=abrir_programa3).pack()
  tk.Button(root, text="Programa 4", command=abrir_programa4).pack()
  root.mainloop()
  ```

  Se puede usar una función anónima también:

  ```
  tk.Button(root, command=lambda: programa1.crear_toplevel(root))
  ```

  **programa1.py**

  ```
  import Tkinter as tk 

  def crear_toplevel(root):
      toplevel = tk.Toplevel(root)
      tk.Label(toplevel, text="Soy Etiqueta 1").pack()
      tk.Label(toplevel, text="Soy Etiqueta 2").pack()
      tk.Label(toplevel, text="Soy Etiqueta 3").pack()
      tk.Label(toplevel, text="Soy Etiqueta 4").pack()
  ```

---

Hay muchas formas de estructurar la App, por ejemplo, un patrón general usando POO puede ser:

**principal.py**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import programa1



class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainApplication, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        tk.Button(self, text="Programa 1", command=self.abrir_ventana1).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Programa 2", command=self.abrir_ventana2).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Programa 3", command=self.abrir_ventana3).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Programa 4", command=self.abrir_ventana4).pack()

    def abrir_ventana1(self):
        top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)
        programa1.Ventana(top_level).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def abrir_ventana2(self):
        pass

    def abrir_ventana3(self):
        pass

    def abrir_ventana4(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

**programa1.py**

```
import Tkinter as tk



class Ventana(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Ventana, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent        
        tk.Label(self, text="Soy Etiqueta 1").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Soy Etiqueta 2").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Soy Etiqueta 3").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Soy Etiqueta 4").pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Ventana(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

lo cual, al implementar todo el contenido en Frames nos permite reutilizar el código pudiendo usar dicho Frame como contenido principal de ventanas secundarias, principales, incluirlo dentro de otro widget en una ventana dada, etc.

Dos comentarios:

- Usar wildcard para importar (`from modulo import *`) es por lo general una mala práctica. Solo debería usarse cuando de forma explícita e intencionada queremos solapar dos espacios de nombres. De hecho importas el módulo de dos formas distintas, usa `import Tkinter as Tk` solo.
- No hagas `b0 = tk.Button(...).pack()` (lo mismo con `grid` o `place`). Al llamar a `pack` en la misma línea en la que instancias el widgets haces que `b0` sea el retorno de `pack`, es decir, `None`. Esto hace que `b0`, `b1`, `b2`, etc sean todas variables asociadas a `None` y por tanto inútiles. Si no necesitas hacer referencia al widgets nunca más simplemente haz:

  ```
  tk.Button(...).pack()
  ```

  si vas a necesitar hacer referencia a él en el futuro, separa la instanciación de la llamada a `grid`/`pack`/`place`:

  ```
  b0 = Button(...)
  b0.pack()
  ```

> **Nota:** el código es para Python 2.x porque es el usado en la pregunta, no obstante para Python 3.x solo hay que cambiar el import:
>
> ```
> import Tkinter as tk
> ```
>
> por:
>
> ```
> import tkinter as tk
> ```
>
> y si queremos podemos simplificar la llamada `super` haciendo simplemente:
>
> ```
> super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

Comment: Use la solución de subprocess para llamar a otros programas python dentro del command (funciones). buenísimo... gracias miileeees!!!