# ¿StringVar y texvariable no funcionan en una ventana secundaria?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Uso `textvariable` para asociar una `StringVar` a un `Label` desde una ventana secundaria que fue llamada desde un comando de otra ventana, el problema es que el valor establecido a través `.set()` no se refleja en el `Label` de la ventana secundaria.

Ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk

def test():
    ven=tk.Tk()
    v1=tk.StringVar()
    v1.set('PRUEBA')
    print(v1.get())
    tk.Label(ven, textvariable=v1).pack()
    ven.mainloop()

win=tk.Tk()
tk.Button(text='BOTON',command=test).pack()
win.mainloop()
```

En este caso, el mensaje 'PRUEBA' establecido a través de `v1.set()` no se actualiza en la `textvariable` del `Label` que fue creado en la función `test()`

¿A qué se debe esto?

Answer (score 3):

En ningún momento la variable pertenece a la ventana secundaria, pertenece a la ventana principal a no ser que especifiques el padre de forma explícita (como ocurre con cualquier otro widget):

```
v1 = tk.StringVar(ven)
```

Ahora bien, en principio jamás debes crear ventanas secundarias de esa forma, cada aplicación de Tkinter (proceso) debe tener **una y solo una instancia de `tkinter.Tk` y un solo ciclo principal (mainloop)**.

Tkinter es realmente un  wrapper que trabaja sobre un intérprete ***tcl*** embebido. Cada **instancia de `Tk` genera un nuevo intérprete y con él un nuevo espacio de nombres (entorno realmente)**, por eso tu segunda ventana (el widget `Label` que tiene ésta como padre) no puede usar la variable que pertenece a la primera. Esto no solo afecta a `StringVar`, en realidad ningún widget perteneciente al entorno de un intérprete puede ser accedido por otro.

No hay realmente una razón específica que impida tener varias instancias de `Tk`, lo que ocurre es que esto raramente va ser de alguna utilidad. En cambio trae problemas importantes consigo, muchos de ellos totalmente silenciosos al producirse a nivel del intérprete tcl sin que se informe al intérprete Python, como el que ha causado esta pregunta. Además tienes más de un intérprete corriendo simultáneamente por lo que consumes recursos, generalmente, de forma innecesaria.

La forma correcta de crear ventanas secundarias generalmente es usar **`tkinter.Toplevel`**:

```
import tkinter as tk


def test():
    ven = tk.Toplevel(win)
    ven.geometry("200x200")
    v1 = tk.StringVar()
    v1.set('PRUEBA')
    tk.Label(ven, textvariable=v1).pack()


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("200x200")
tk.Button(win, text='BOTON', command=test).pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Ten en cuenta que al crear la variable dentro de la función, `v1` es una variable de ámbito local por lo que no podrás usarla desde la ventana principal. Si quieres usarla en ambas ventanas debes declararla fuera de la función, globalmente:

```
import tkinter as tk


def test():
    ven = tk.Toplevel(master=win)
    ven.geometry("200x200")
    tk.Label(ven, text="Ingrese un valor: ").pack()
    tk.Entry(ven, textvariable=v1).pack()


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("200x200")
v1 = tk.StringVar(win)
tk.Button(win,text='Abrir secundaria', command=test).pack()
tk.Label(win, textvariable=v1).pack()
win.mainloop()
```