# Pasar Parámetros a una función para insertarlos en una tabla

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, sqlite3

> Recién acabo de terminar mi curso de Python y estoy intentado hacer un sistema de inventario simplificado. El programa consta de varias ventanas (para agregar algún ítem, para modificarlo, etc...). La idea del código que voy a colocar a continuación es que al momento de presionar el botón de "Crear", el mismo llame a una función pasándole los parámetros especificados en el código. He intentado de muchas formas posibles sin éxito alguno de que se pasen correctamente los parámetros. código:

```py
def crear(datos1):

    con=sqlite3.connect("Inventario")
    cur=con.cursor()

    try:

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO INVENTARIO VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)", (datos1))

        con.commit()

        messagebox.showinfo("Agregar","Registro Agregado")

    except:

        messagebox.showwarning("Error","Ha ocurrido un error")

def agregar():

    root=Tk()

    pro=StringVar()
    pre=StringVar()
    can=StringVar()
    var=StringVar()

    frame1=Frame(root)
    frame1.pack()

    entry1=Entry(frame1, textvariable=pro)
    entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    entry2=Entry(frame1, textvariable=pre)
    entry2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    entry3=Entry(frame1, textvariable=can)
    entry3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    rb1=Radiobutton(frame1, text="Producto", variable=var, value="Producto")
    rb1.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")
    rb2=Radiobutton(frame1, text="Servicio", variable=var, value="Servicio")
    rb2.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="w")

    label1=Label(frame1, text="Producto:")
    label1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    label1=Label(frame1, text="Precio:")
    label1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    label1=Label(frame1, text="Cantidad:")
    label1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    label1=Label(frame1, text="Tipo:")
    label1.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    frame2=Frame(root)
    frame2.pack()

    datos=pro.get(), pre.get(), can.get(), var.get()

    boton1=Button(frame2, text="Agregar", command=lambda:crear(datos))
    boton1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)

    boton2=Button(frame2, text="Cancelar", command=lambda:root.destroy())
    boton2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)

    root.mainloop()

Gracias de antemano.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe al **momento en el que es evaluada** la línea:

```
datos=pro.get(), pre.get(), can.get(), var.get()
```

esta línea se evalúa al ejecutar la función `agregar`, antes incluso de que la composición de la app esté completa y de que se muestre en pantalla (antes del mainloop). En ese momento todos los entries están lógicamente vacíos por lo que a `crear` **siempre se le manda una tupla con cuatro cadenas vacías**.

Debes **obtener los cuatro valores en el momento en el que se pulsa el botón**, no cuando la función es llamada. Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, pero sin modificar tu idea original puede simplemente valerte de que las expresiones lambda se evalúan en diferido, es decir, cuando son llamadas y no al ser definidas:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk


def crear(datos1):
    con = sqlite3.connect("Inventario")
    cur = con.cursor()

    try:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO INVENTARIO VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)", datos1)
        con.commit()
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Agregar","Registro Agregado")
    except:
        tk.messagebox.showwarning("Error","Ha ocurrido un error")
    finally:
        cur.close()
        con.close()


def agregar():

    root = tk.Tk()

    pro = tk.StringVar(root)
    pre = tk.StringVar(root)
    can = tk.StringVar(root)
    var = tk.StringVar(root)

    frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
    frame1.pack()

    entry1 = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=pro)
    entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    entry2 = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=pre)
    entry2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    entry3 = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=can)
    entry3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(frame1, text="Producto", variable=var, value="Producto")
    rb1.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")
    rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(frame1, text="Servicio", variable=var, value="Servicio")
    rb2.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="w")

    label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Producto:")
    label1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    label2 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Precio:")
    label2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    label3 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Cantidad:")
    label3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    label4 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Tipo:")
    label4.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
    frame2.pack()

    crear_wrapper = lambda: crear((pro.get(), pre.get(), can.get(), var.get()))

    boton1 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Agregar", command=crear_wrapper)
    boton1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)

    boton2 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Cancelar", command=root.destroy)
    boton2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    agregar()
```

Ten en cuenta que no necesitas usar lambda si la función no recibe argumentos, basta con pasar una referencia a la función en este caso (`command=root.destroy` en vez de `command=lambda:root.destroy()`):

- [¿Cómo actuan las funciones lambda en este código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270617/c%c3%b3mo-actuan-las-funciones-lambda-en-este-c%c3%b3digo)

---

### Edición

Dado que la función agregar es lanzada al pulsar un botón en otra ventana debes tener en cuenta algunas cosas más:

- **Pasa siempre el padre a los widget**, incluidas las variables (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc).
- **No debes usar en principio más de una sola instancia de `tkinter.Tk` en una aplicación**. Si necesitas más ventanas usa `TopLevel`, mira esta pregunta relacionada:

  - [¿StringVar y texvariable no funcionan en una ventana secundaria?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/283262/15089)

Tu función debería quedar:

```
def agregar(root=None):

    window = Toplevel(root)

    pro = StringVar(window)
    pre = StringVar(window)
    can = StringVar(window)
    var = StringVar(window)

    frame1 = Frame(window)
    frame1.pack()

    entry1 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=pro)
    entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    entry2 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=pre)
    entry2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    entry3 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=can)
    entry3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    rb1 = Radiobutton(frame1, text="Producto", variable=var, value="Producto")
    rb1.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")
    rb2 = Radiobutton(frame1, text="Servicio", variable=var, value="Servicio")
    rb2.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="w")

    label1 = Label(frame1, text="Producto:")
    label1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    label1 = Label(frame1, text="Precio:")
    label1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    label1 = Label(frame1, text="Cantidad:")
    label1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    label1 = Label(frame1, text="Tipo:")
    label1.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    frame2 = Frame(window)
    frame2.pack()

    boton1 = Button(frame2, text="Agregar", command=lambda: crear((pro.get(), pre.get(), can.get(), var.get())))
    boton1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)

    boton2=Button(frame2, text="Cancelar", command=window.destroy)
    boton2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)

    window.mainloop()
```

y debes llamarla mediante:

```
invMenu.add_command(label="Agregar Item", command=lambda: F.agregar(root))
```

Comment: Gracias por la rápida respuesta. He intentado aplicar el código que me has pasado pero no tuvo éxito alguno. Puedo adjuntar un PasteBin con el código completo y original para ver si el error está de antes. Gracias

Interfaz:[https://pastebin.com/z2GGaYXm]
Funciones:[https://pastebin.com/uuHjvaXd]

Comment: Hola Mauricio, los pastebin aparecen como eliminados, no obstante puedes hacer print(datos1) al inicio de la función crear a ver que recibe. ¿Cuando dices que no funciona que es lo que ocurre?¿algún error?¿Te muestra el messagebox?

Comment: Hola. Cometí un error al publicar los links, los dejaré más abajo en el comentario. Si me sale el messagebox pero cuando introduzco los datos en la ventana que genera la función "agregar" y presiono el botón "Crear" se crea un registro vacío en la BBDD (solo se crea el ID que esta como AUTOINCREMENT), es decir, los datos que le paso a la función "crear" no llegan a dicha función. Adjunto los links corregidos:
Interfaz: https://pastebin.com/z2GGaYXm
Funciones: https://pastebin.com/uuHjvaXd

Comment: Mauricio mira la edición a la pregunta, debería resolver tu problema.

Comment: Gracias!! Ahora sí funciona como debería. Gracias por la ayuda y la paciencia.!