# ¿Cómo crear pestañas independientes con ttk.Notebook?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

**Hola Comunidad!!**

Recientemente he estado en desarrollo de una App que realice múltiples tareas. He estado implementando la librería `tkinter` y sus diversas funcionalidades.

Llevo un par de días sin poder avanzar porque durante la puesta en marcha de la App me he fijado que presenta un error lógico, es decir, el programa fluye sin que el intérprete de `Python 3.x` capte algún tipo de error.

Para ser más específico, creé otro archivo que reflejara el mismo tipo de problema, pero de forma mucho más resumida. Consiste en una *GUI* que contiene en su interior un widget `ttk.Notebook` con una pestaña llamada *"INICIO"* que alberga un botón para realizar una operación matemática (suma).

Al hacer click sobre dicho botón se crea una nueva pestaña llamada "Pestaña de sumar". Dentro de ella estarán una serie de widgets que capturan los valores que ingresa el usuario y muestran su resultado al hacer click sobre un botón de "calcular". Hasta allí, todo funciona a la perfección. Ahora, sucede que si se devuelve a la pestaña "INICIO" y se vuelve a seleccionar el botón de "suma" se creará otra pestaña para realizar el mismo calculo y funciona a la perfección pero, en la pestaña creada anteriormente ya no se podrá realizar la operación porque ya no se capturan los valores que son ingresados.

En resumen, quiero que cuando el usuario deseé abrir una cantidad ilimitada de pestañas con el mismo contenido que funcionen cada una independiente, es decir, que puedan ejecutar la misma operación bajo distintos valores ingresados.

He aquí el código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Mi_App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.configure(width=650, height=650)

        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.fm = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.fm, text='INICIO')
        self.nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        tk.Label(self.fm, text='Bienvenido a mi programa').grid()

        tk.Button(self.fm, text='Sumar', command=lambda:self.sum()).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)

    def sum(self):
        self.fm_sumar = tk.LabelFrame(self.nb, text='Aquí se realizará la operación')
        self.nb.add(self.fm_sumar, text='Pestaña de sumar') 
        self.nb.select(self.fm_sumar)

        self.valor1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.valor2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.resultado = tk.IntVar()

        def calcular():
            self.resultado.set(self.valor1.get() + self.valor2.get())

        tk.Label(self.fm_sumar, text='Valor 1:').grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(self.fm_sumar, text='Valor 2:').grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.fm_sumar, text='¡Calcular!', command=lambda:calcular()).grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Label(self.fm_sumar, text='Resultado=').grid(row=3, column=0)

        tk.Entry(self.fm_sumar, textvariable=self.valor1, justify='right').grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Entry(self.fm_sumar, textvariable=self.valor2, justify='right').grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Entry(self.fm_sumar, textvariable=self.resultado, justify='right', state='readonly').grid(row=3, column=1)


    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = Mi_App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que en Python una función normal (no `lambda`) efectivamente se evalúa en el ámbito en el que es definida, pero **el cuerpo de dicha función no es evaluado hasta que es ejecutada** (late binding). En tu caso haces los siguiente:

```
self.valor1 = tk.IntVar()
self.valor2 = tk.IntVar()
self.resultado = tk.IntVar()

def calcular():
    self.resultado.set(self.valor1.get() + self.valor2.get())
```

en cada pestaña que creas generas una nueva instancia de cada una de las variables, pero se las asignas a atributos de instancia. Cuando la función es llamada usa las referencias de esos atributos de instancia, pero éstos hacen referencia a las variables de la última pestaña creada, fijate lo que pasa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la función `calcular` se ejecuta pero actúa sobre la última pestaña creada siempre, independientemente desde que pestaña sea llamada. La solución es tan simple como no usar un atributo de instancia, sino variables locales de forma que la clausura acceda en cada caso a las de esa pestaña.

```
def sum(self):
    fm_sumar = tk.LabelFrame(
        self.nb, text='Aquí se realizará la operación'
        )
    self.nb.add(fm_sumar, text='Pestaña de sumar')
    self.nb.select(fm_sumar)

    valor1 = tk.IntVar(fm_sumar)
    valor2 = tk.IntVar(fm_sumar)
    resultado = tk.IntVar(fm_sumar)

    def calcular():
        resultado.set(valor1.get() + valor2.get())

    tk.Label(fm_sumar, text='Valor 1:').grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Label(fm_sumar, text='Valor 2:').grid(row=1, column=0)
    tk.Button(
        fm_sumar, text='¡Calcular!', command=calcular
        ).grid(row=2, column=0)
    tk.Label(fm_sumar, text='Resultado=').grid(row=3, column=0)

    tk.Entry(
        fm_sumar, textvariable=valor1, justify='right'
        ).grid(row=0, column=1)
    tk.Entry(
        fm_sumar, textvariable=valor2, justify='right'
        ).grid(row=1, column=1)
    tk.Entry(
        fm_sumar, textvariable=resultado, justify='right',
        state='readonly'
        ).grid(row=3, column=1)
```

Otra posibilidad es que la callback use las variables como argumentos por defecto:

```
def sum(self):
    self.fm_sumar = tk.LabelFrame(self.nb, text='Aquí se realizará la operación')
    self.nb.add(self.fm_sumar, text='Pestaña de sumar') 
    self.nb.select(self.fm_sumar)

    self.valor1 = tk.IntVar()
    self.valor2 = tk.IntVar()
    self.resultado = tk.IntVar()

    def calcular(resul=self.resultado, v1=self.valor1, v2=self.valor2):
        resul.set(v1.get() + v2.get())

    tk.Label(self.fm_sumar, text='Valor 1:').grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Label(self.fm_sumar, text='Valor 2:').grid(row=1, column=0)
    tk.Button(
        self.fm_sumar, text='¡Calcular!', command=calcular
        ).grid(row=2, column=0)
    tk.Label(self.fm_sumar, text='Resultado=').grid(row=3, column=0)

    tk.Entry(
        self.fm_sumar, textvariable=self.valor1, justify='right'
        ).grid(row=0, column=1)
    tk.Entry(
        self.fm_sumar, textvariable=self.valor2, justify='right'
        ).grid(row=1, column=1)
    tk.Entry(
        self.fm_sumar, textvariable=self.resultado,
        justify='right', state='readonly'
        ).grid(row=3, column=1)
```

¿Por qué ahora si funciona? Los argumentos de la función son evaluados en tiempo de definición, no cuando es ejecutada como el cuerpo. Ésto hace que las variables `resul`, `v1` y `v2` apunten a los objetos a los que apuntaban `self.reultado`, `self.valor1` y `self.valor2` respectivamente cuando la función se definió, es decir, cuando `sum` se ejecutó. Esta es una técnica común para evitar los problemas derivados del late binding que funciona tanto con métodos/funciones normales como con lambdas, otra es usar `functools.partial`.

Ahora bien, dado que usas POO, tiene mucha más lógica, es más simple y escalable crear una clase para el frame de suma que encapsule todo lo que le pertenece, como las variables:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class SumFrame(tk.LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.valor1 = tk.IntVar(self)
        self.valor2 = tk.IntVar(self)
        self.resultado = tk.IntVar(self)

        tk.Label(self, text='Valor 1:').grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(self, text='Valor 2:').grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(
            self, text='¡Calcular!', command=self.calcular
            ).grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Label(self, text='Resultado=').grid(row=3, column=0)

        tk.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self.valor1, justify='right'
            ).grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self.valor2, justify='right'
            ).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self.resultado, justify='right',
            state='readonly'
            ).grid(row=3, column=1)

    def calcular(self):
        self.resultado.set(self.valor1.get() + self.valor2.get())


class Mi_App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("650x250")

        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.fm = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.fm, text='INICIO')
        self.nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        tk.Label(self.fm, text='Bienvenido a mi programa').grid()

        tk.Button(
            self.fm, text='Sumar', command=self.sum
            ).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)

    def sum(self):
        fm_sumar = SumFrame(self)
        self.nb.add(fm_sumar, text='Pestaña de sumar')
        self.nb.select(fm_sumar)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = Mi_App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Dos observaciones:

- Pasa siempre a las variables su widget padre, en el fondo se comportan como widgets y si no se les pasa un padre automáticamene toman la instancia de `tkinter.Tk` como tal. Ésto causa a veces problemas inesperados:

  - [¿StringVar y texvariable no funcionan en una ventana secundaria?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283262/stringvar-y-texvariable-no-funcionan-en-una-ventana-secundaria)
- No necesitas, ni debes, usar una función lambda como envoltorio cuando no necesitas pasar argumentos a la callback.