# estoy creando un login con tkinter y no logro que se abran las otras ventanas

Tags: python, tkinter

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]espero de todo corazón que se encuentren muy bien.
estoy intentando hacer una pequeña practica de un login que en teoría al introducir la contraseña correcta debe cerrarse la ventana de login para abrirse otra diferente con una imagen de felicitaciones, pero no ocurre solo me marca un error de que no puede abrir la imagen y si aplico la sangria a todo el codigo de root2 me dice que no lo he definido y tampoco funciona. lamentablemente soy autodidacta y no logro identificar aun como acomodar el codigo ya que si lo muevo hacia arriba donde puse el codigo de la ventana se buguea completamente o no se que comando pueda hacer falta.
espero me puedan ayudar gracias de antemano.[![dejo imagenes para ejemplificar ambas situaciones][1]][1\

````
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import FALSE

#tamaño y fondo de la ventana
ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title('tejon login')
ventana.geometry('500x500+500+50')
ventana.resizable(width=False, height=False)
fondo=tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Victor\\Documents\\proyectos python\\cuevita login.png')
fondo1=tk.Label(ventana, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)



usuario=tk.StringVar
pasword=tk.StringVar

#entradas
entrada=tk.Entry(ventana, textvar=usuario, width=30, relief='flat', bg='pink')
entrada.place(x=215, y=280)

entrada2=tk.Entry(ventana, textvar=pasword, width=30, relief='flat', bg='pink', show='*')
entrada2.place(x=215, y=350)

def correcta():  
    ventana.withdraw()
root2=tk.Tk()
root2.title('welcome')
root2.geometry('500x500+500+50')  
root2.resizable(width=False, height=False)
fondoWelcome=tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Victor\\Documents\\proyectos python\\karina.png')
fondoWel=tk.Label(root2, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

def login():
    nombre=usuario.get()
    contraseña=pasword.get()
if entrada=='perriquito' and entrada2=='crux':
    correcta()
else:
    incorrecta()


boton_entrar=tk.Button(ventana, text='ENTRAR', command=login, cursor="hand2", bg='red', width=20, height=2)
boton_entrar.place(x=200, y=410)


ventana.mainloop()```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWudG.png
````

Comment: Hola Salvatore. Tienes que poner el código de las 'def' justo después de hacer las import, y antes de comenzar a establecer el diseño de la interfaz. Y además tienes que indentar el código de las 'def' correctamente.

Comment: Por otro lado, hay muchas cosas en tu código que están mal. Te recomiendo que visites esta otra pregunta, que te resolvera otros problemas que te surgen: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283262/stringvar-y-texvariable-no-funcionan-en-una-ventana-secundaria

Comment: Por último, te recomiendo que uses 'grid()' en lugar de 'pack()' o 'place()'. En diseños más complejos es mucho más potente y versátil, y su uso está recomendado como preferente desde la versión 3.10. Aquí un buen artículo al respecto: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/posicionar-elementos-en-tkinter/